# Когда происходит выход из цикла for?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void showflags(ios::fmtflags f);

int main()
{
    ios::fmtflags f;

    f = cout.flags();
    showflags(f);

    cout.setf(ios::showpos | ios::scientific);
    f = cout.flags();
    showflags(f);

    cout.unsetf(ios::scientific);
    f = cout.flags();
    showflags(f);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void showflags(ios::fmtflags f)
{
    long i;

    cout << "std flag: " << f << " = ";
    for (i = 0x4000; i; i = i >> 1) {
        if (i & f) cout << "1 ";
        else cout << "0 ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Я так понимаю, переменная **i** функции showflags() постепенно заполняется единицами:
до начала цикла:
100000000000000
после первой итерации:
110000000000000
...
после четырнадцатой итерации:
111111111111111

Что значит здесь: `for (i = 0x4000; i; i = i >> 1)` "до **i**"?
Объясните, пожалуйста, условие выхода из цикла.
И ещё вопрос, как происходит побитовое сравнение: `if (i & f)` ?
Что даёт истину, что ложь?

Comment: Вообще отладчик крайне полезная штука, зря вы им не пользуетесь. i = i >> 1 - деление на два. Фактически, i=i/2 там написано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение, используемое в условии предложения if неявно преобразуется к типу bool по следующему правилу:

в частности арифметическое выражение равное нулю преобразуется к `false`. Любое другое значение преобразуется к булеву значению `true`.

Следовательно этот цикла завершится

```
for (i = 0x4000; i; i = i >> 1) {
```

когда выражение в его условии `i` станет равным 0.

Лучше представить инициализатор `i` в двоичном виде

```
0x4000 => 0b0100 0000 0000 0000
```

После каждого сдвига вправо `i = i >> 1` на одну позицию `1` будет смещаться вправо, а освободившиеся позиции будут заполняться нулем. Например

```
0b0100 0000 0000 0000
0b0010 0000 0000 0000
0b0001 0000 0000 0000
//...
0b0000 0000 0000 0001
0b0000 0000 0000 0000
```

пока 1 не будет вытеснена из числа. В этом случае `i` станет равным `0` и итерации цикла прекратятся.

Что касается вопроса

> И ещё вопрос, как происходит побитовое сравнение: if (i & f) ? Что
>   даёт истину, что ложь?

то таблица результатов операции с битами AND выглядит следующим образом

```
0 & 0 = 0 
0 & 1 = 0
1 & 0 = 0
1 & 1 = 1
```

То есть когда два бита в соответствующих позициях равны 1, то результат применения к ним оператора `&` также будет равен 1.

Следовательно в этом выражении

```
i & f
```

проверяется, установлен ли во флаге `f` бит, соответствующий установленному биту в числе `i`, и если установлен то это выражение при неявном преобразовании к булеву типу будет равно `true`, иначе `false`. То есть благодаря сдвигу единичного бита в числе `i` в цикле `for` последовательно проверяется установлен ли в единицу соответствующий бит во флаге `f`

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался.

Comment: @Dim Team Не за что.:)

Comment: На сколько я понял, если i = 0b0101, x = 0b0010, то такая операция даст false : i & x, а если x = 0b0001, то даст true, верно? Т.е. в одном из сравниваемых операндов должны быть все числа, кроме одного нули(в двоичной системе)?

Comment: @Dim Team В первом случае действительно результат будет false, так как ни одна пара соответствующих битов в двух числах не равны 1. Во втором случае результат будет true, так как биты в самом младшем разряде обоих числе установлены в 1 и соответственно результат операции & будет число равное x. которое отлично от нуля

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow Выходит, сравнивать можно только с чем-то таким: 0b0000 0010 (где установлен только один бит)? Нельзя сравнивать(оператором &) например такие числа: 0b0101 0101 и 0b0001 0010? Как в таком случае будет определяться истина/ложь?

Comment: @Dim Team При использовании оператора & с целыми числами этот оператор применяется к каждой паре соответствующих битов. В результирующем числе соответствующий бит будет установлен равным 1 если оба бита соответствующей пара битов исходных чисел также равны 1. Если результирующее число не равно нулю, (какие-то его биты установлены в 1),  то в предложении if оно неявно преобразуется к булеву значению true.

Answer (score 2):

> Что значит здесь: `for (i = 0x4000; i; i = i >> 1)` "до i"? Объясните,
>   пожалуйста, условие выхода из цикла.

Стандарт определяет оператор `for` следующим образом (**[stmt.for]**):

> The for statement
>
> ```
> for ( for-init-statement condition (optional); expression (optional)) statement
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     for-init-statement
>     while ( condition ) {
>         statement
>         expression ;
>     }
> }
> ```

Для цикла `while` стандарт определяет следующее поведение: тело цикла выполняется до тех пор, пока условие не станет `false` (**[stmt.while]**)

> In the `while` statement the substatement is executed repeatedly until
>   the value of the `condition` (6.4) becomes `false`. The test takes
>   place before each execution of the substatement.

Пункт **[conv.bool]** определяет булевы преобразования следующим образом:

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to
>   member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero
>   value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
>   to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`. A prvalue of type
>   `std::nullptr_t` can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`; the
>   resulting value is `false`.

Таким образом, цикл будет продолжаться до тех пор, пока переменная `i` не примет нулевое значение.

---

> И ещё вопрос, как происходит побитовое сравнение: if (i & f) ? Что
>   даёт истину, что ложь?

Для полноты картины приведу цитату из стандарта (**[expr.bit.and]**):

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed; the result is the
>   bitwise `AND` function of the operands. The operator applies only to
>   integral or unscoped enumeration operands.

Соответственно, к условию `if (i & f)` также применима выдержка из стандарта **[conv.bool]**

Answer (score 1):

В языке C++ числовые значения, употребляемые в булевом контексте (например, внутри `if`), преобразуются к `bool`. При этом ненулевые значения «превращаются» в `true`, а ноль — в `false`.

То же относится и к указателям: ненулевой указатель в `if` (или проверке условия в `for`) работает как `true`, ненулевой — как `false`.

Это правило унаследовано C++ из его предшественника C. В C, кстати, нет булевого типа¹, поэтому там просто в проверках разрешены числа и указатели.

---

¹не было тогда, когда от него произошёл C++; сейчас появился